# How to hide a border when a collapsible container is hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css, border

I am trying to hide the border of a collapsible drawer when it is closed. Currently, it still shows the border when it is closed, indicated by the line under each drawer selector. How would I go about hiding it?

HTML:

```
        <button type="button" class="collapsible"> Loose Crimp Issue </button>

        <div class="content">
          <div class="column">
            <p>Check that the wires and crimps are fully inserted into J1, J4, and trandsducer connectors.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <img src="../images/looseCrimp.png" alt="Picture of Connectors">
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

```js
        var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
          coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.maxHeight){
              content.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
              content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
          });
        }
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
        <button type="button" class="collapsible"> Consult Logs </button>

        <div class="content">
          <div class="column">
            <p>Ensure the disc strength is not at “0”.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <img src="../images/discStrength.png" alt="Picture of Logs">
          </div>
        </div>
```

I tried to hide and show the border on click. It worked once, then just deleted the border after the first time.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to hide the element.

Comment: This is how I am hiding the element.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CEY-aAG3ELXgawCVyrZ9BMG7rRz-fYrR?usp=share_link

Comment: Post code in your question.

Comment: Thank you, the question is now updated to include the JS I am using to collapse the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to also set `border-width: 0` and apply a transition to it:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button')
const collapsible = document.querySelector('.collapsible')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const content = collapsible.querySelector('.content')
    
  collapsible.style.setProperty('--maxHeight', `${ content.offsetHeight }px`)
  collapsible.classList.toggle('expanded')
})
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.collapsible {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  max-height: 0;
  border: 0px solid #D1D3D4;
  transition:
    max-height 0.2s ease-out,
    border 0.2s ease-out;
}

.collapsible.expanded {
  max-height: var(--maxHeight, 256px);
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">Loose Crimp Issue</button>

<div class="collapsible">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="column">
      <p>Check that the wires and crimps are fully inserted into J1, J4, and trandsducer connectors.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <p>Check that the wires and crimps are fully inserted into J1, J4, and trandsducer connectors.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <p>Check that the wires and crimps are fully inserted into J1, J4, and trandsducer connectors.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, move the styling of the card (`border`, `border-radius`, `padding`, etc.) to a new child inside the element you are going to collapse (the one that gets the `max-height`:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button')
const collapsible = document.querySelector('.collapsible')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const content = collapsible.querySelector('.content')
    
  collapsible.style.setProperty('--maxHeight', `${ content.offsetHeight }px`)
  collapsible.classList.toggle('expanded')
})
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.collapsible {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition:max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.collapsible.expanded {
  max-height: var(--maxHeight, 256px);
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">Loose Crimp Issue</button>

<div class="collapsible">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="column">
      <p>Check that the wires and crimps are fully inserted into J1, J4, and trandsducer connectors.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <p>Check that the wires and crimps are fully inserted into J1, J4, and trandsducer connectors.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <p>Check that the wires and crimps are fully inserted into J1, J4, and trandsducer connectors.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

First solution (set `border-width: 0`) with your original code (without using additional CSS classes):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible").forEach((coll) => {
  coll.addEventListener("click", () => {
    coll.classList.toggle("active");
    
    const content = coll.nextElementSibling;
    
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
      // Add this:
      content.style.borderWidth = 0;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      // And this:
      content.style.borderWidth = "1px";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Change this: */
  transition:
    border 0.2s ease-out,
    max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: white;
  /* And this: */
  border: 0px solid #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible"> Consult Logs </button>

<div class="content">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Ensure the disc strength is not at “0”.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="../images/discStrength.png" alt="Picture of Logs">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I really appreciate the help but I can't seem to get it to work with my document structure, and I am running an additional script for collapsing. Could you have a look at my code as a whole?
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CEY-aAG3ELXgawCVyrZ9BMG7rRz-fYrR?usp=share_link

Comment: If the issue is somewhere else in your code, please create a Minimal, Reproducible example here on StackOverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you, the question is now updated to include the JS I am using to collapse the elements.

Comment: I've added your code with 4 changes to make it work. Anyway, I advise you to review the other solutions and do it using CSS classes rather than changing the `style` attribute with JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the button when it is clicked (using `onclick`), and use that to modify the CSS for the .collapsible class to remove the border when that class is present. Here's an (untested) example:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="collapsible" onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">Loose Crimp Issue</button>

<div class="content">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Check that the wires and crimps are fully inserted into J1, J4, and transducer connectors.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="../images/looseCrimp.png" alt="Picture of Connectors">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.collapsible.active {
  border: none;
}
```